# How to draw a graph G=(9,11) in latex?

Tags: diagrams, graphs

I am currently trying to draw this diagram. Any help would greatly
appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is via TikZ. The `foreach`-loop abbreviates the code. Basically, for every `n` in {1,...,9} we run the command `\filldraw (vn) circle (1pt);`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \coordinate (v1) at (0,2);
      \coordinate (v2) at (1,2);
      \coordinate (v3) at (2,2);
      \coordinate (v4) at (0,1);
      \coordinate (v5) at (1,1);
      \coordinate (v6) at (2,1);
      \coordinate (v7) at (0,0);
      \coordinate (v8) at (1,0);
      \coordinate (v9) at (2,0);
      
      \foreach\n in {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}{\filldraw (v\n) circle (1pt);}
      \draw[thick] (v7) -- (v1) -- (v3) -- (v9);
      \draw[thick] (v2) -- (v5);
      \draw[thick] (v6) -- (v8);
      \draw (v4) -- (v5) -- (v3);
      \draw (v8) -- (v9);
      
      \draw (v1) node[anchor=south east] {$v_1$};
      \draw (v2) node[anchor=south]      {$v_2$};
      \draw (v3) node[anchor=south west] {$v_3$};
      \draw (v4) node[anchor=east]       {$v_4$};
      \draw (v5) node[anchor=north west] {$v_5$};
      \draw (v6) node[anchor=west]       {$v_6$};
      \draw (v7) node[anchor=north east] {$v_7$};
      \draw (v8) node[anchor=north]      {$v_8$};
      \draw (v9) node[anchor=north west] {$v_9$};
      
      \draw (-1,1) node[anchor=east] {$G=$};
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Elise, it seems that the answer is helpfull for your. So please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) it (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).